# How to copy/paste in HTML?

Tags: javascript

I have a site with Drupal 8 and I want to do a "copy" text with a button in TWIG.

How can I do this ?

I need to make a copy to two different place on the same page :

```
<div>
  <small id="copy-to-clipboard-text-share">{{ url('<current>') }}</small>
  <button id="copy-to-clipboard-btn-share" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-files" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M13 0H6a2 2 0 0 0-2 2 2 2 0 0 0-2 2v10a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h7a2 2 0 0 0 2-2 2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2zm0 13V4a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H5a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h7a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v10a1 1 0 0 1-1 1zM3 4a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h7a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v10a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H4a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V4z"/></svg>
  </button>
</div>

<div>
  <small id="copy-to-clipboard-text-btc">{{ group.field_groupe_donation.value }}</small>
  <button id="copy-to-clipboard-btn-btc" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-files" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M13 0H6a2 2 0 0 0-2 2 2 2 0 0 0-2 2v10a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h7a2 2 0 0 0 2-2 2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2zm0 13V4a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H5a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h7a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v10a1 1 0 0 1-1 1zM3 4a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h7a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v10a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H4a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V4z"/></svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: you can't do it without `js`.

Comment: you can only make copy the content of one element and paste it on the page by js, but can not access the clipboard of the operating system.

Comment: What should I put as JS code to make a copy with the button ?